# Terraform v0.12.1 error Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": element 0: string required

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I just updated from Terraform v0.11.11 to v0.12.1 and I am now seeing these issues.  I get the whole list in a list thing but I have tried every which way to fix this with no luck. I have removed the LBracket after ***cidr_blocks = [*** with no luck I have tried warpping in ***${}*** no go. I have tried removing the lbrackets after the var.cidr_groups.. like so with no luck ***var.cidr_groups"mainoffice"***. Where am I going wrong here?

```
resource "aws_security_group" "common_access" {
  name        = "common_access"
  description = "common_access"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.myvcp.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [ 
      var.cidr_groups["mainoffice"],
      var.cidr_groups["manchester"],
      var.cidr_groups["singapore"],
      var.cidr_groups["jena"],
      var.cidr_groups["fremont"],
      var.cidr_groups["indianapolis"],
    ]
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"

# TF-UPGRADE-TODO: In Terraform v0.10 and earlier, it was sometimes necessary to
    # force an interpolation expression to be interpreted as a list by wrapping it
    # in an extra set of list brackets. That form was supported for compatibilty in
    # v0.11, but is no longer supported in Terraform v0.12.
    #
    # If the expression in the following list itself returns a list, remove the
    # brackets to avoid interpretation as a list of lists. If the expression
    # returns a single list item then leave it as-is and remove this TODO comment.

    cidr_blocks = var.cidr_groups["PublicAll"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name      = "common_access"
    owner     = var.contact
    terraform = true
  }
}
```

Vairables file for the ***var.cidr_groups*** looks like this

```
variable "cidr_groups" {
  default = {
    mainoffice              = ["10.200.0.0/15"]
    manchester              = ["10.201.0.0/16"]
    singapore               = ["10.202.0.0/16"]
    jena                    = ["10.203.0.0/16"]
    fremont                 = ["10.204.0.0/16"]
    indianapolis            = ["10.205.0.0/16"]
     
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `var.cidr_groups["PublicAll"]` which isn't defined. Try using this instead.

I removed the square brackets from `var.cidr_groups` and added `PublicAll`.

```
variable "cidr_groups" {
  default = {
    mainoffice   = "10.200.0.0/15"
    manchester   = "10.201.0.0/16"
    singapore    = "10.202.0.0/16"
    jena         = "10.203.0.0/16"
    fremont      = "10.204.0.0/16"
    indianapolis = "10.205.0.0/16"
    PublicAll    = "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
}
```

Keep the ingress `cidr_blocks` the same and then use this for egress.

```
  cidr_blocks = [var.cidr_groups["PublicAll"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to `flatten`

```
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = flatten ([ 
      var.cidr_groups["mainoffice"],
      var.cidr_groups["manchester"],
      var.cidr_groups["singapore"],
      var.cidr_groups["jena"],
      var.cidr_groups["fremont"],
      var.cidr_groups["indianapolis"],
    ]
  }
```